# Add modelStateDictionary.AddModelError to list of collections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using `modelStateDictionary.AddModelError` to add validation if there are any errors occurring in the model while posting the form ..this is working for actual class properties

I have a class like this

```
public class SuperClass
{
    public EmployeeFamilyTable tbl { get; set; }
}
```

EmployeeFamilyTable contains some fields those are

```
public class EmployeeFamilyTable
    {
        public EmployeeFamilyTable()
        {
            familyMembersList = new List<EmployeeFamilyTable>();
        }
        public List<EmployeeFamilyTable> familyMembersList { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeFamilyDetailId { get; set; }

       
        public string EmployeeFamilyPersonName { get; set; }

       
        public DateTime? EmployeeFamilyPersonDateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
}





public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        bool CreateEmployee(EmployeeFamilyTable mainTbl);
       

    }



public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
        private IValidationDictionary _validatonDictionary;
        public EmployeeService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary)
        {
            _validatonDictionary = validationDictionary;
        }


        public bool ValidateEmployee(EmployeeFamilyTable mainTableToValidate)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mainTableToValidate.familyMembersList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (mainTableToValidate.familyMembersList[i].EmployeeFamilyPersonName == null)
                    _validatonDictionary.AddError("mainTableToValidate.familyMembersList[i].EmployeeFamilyPersonName", "Name is required.");
                if (mainTableToValidate.familyMembersList[i].EmployeeFamilyPersonDateOfBirth == null)
                    _validatonDictionary.AddError("EmployeeFamilyPersonDateOfBirth", "Date of birth is required.");
            }
            return _validatonDictionary.IsValid;
        }


      

        
        public bool CreateEmployee(EmployeeFamilyTable EmployeeToCreate)
        {
            return (!ValidateEmployee(EmployeeToCreate)) ? false :true;            
        }

        
    }


}
```

this is not showing errors in the view, I think I am getting problem in dictionary key.

I am calling this validation method in a controller like this

```
public ActionResult CreateStudent(SuperClass objstudentmodel)
        {
            

            if (!_service.CreateEmployee(objstudentmodel.tbl))
            {
//code goes here



public interface IValidationDictionary
    {
        void AddError(string key, string errorMessage);
        bool IsValid { get; }
    }
```

`modelstatewrapperclass` contains

```
public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
{

    private ModelStateDictionary _modelState;

    public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        _modelState = modelState;
    }

    #region IValidationDictionary Members

    public void AddError(string key, string errorMessage)
    {
        _modelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return _modelState.IsValid; }
    }
```

Comment: What is "key not showing error"? At least elaborate the error and where exactly you are getting the error. Plus how are you creating the mainTableToValidate object?

Comment: Please help me am not getting errors in view

Comment: In what view? Are you using visual studio? Are you running the application in debug mode? The you an click on View Detail of the application to get the details. Share screenshots if you are not clear.

Comment: hi Validation messages not showing  because please look into public bool employeevalidate(employeefamilytable obj)

Comment: Am using visual studio

Comment: I still dont know the exact exception details you are geting. Can you post the exception message. There is a possibility that you are adding the same key to the validation dictionary. If there is more than one employee with employeeFamilyPersonName is null, you would add the same key "mainTableToValidate.familyMembersList[i].EmployeeFamilyPersonName" twice in the dictionary.

Comment: if we use mainTableToValidate.familyMembersList[i].EmployeeFamilyPersonName in place of key it giving null value because it is a string